# Change x/y-coordinate of ellipse

Tags: f#, ellipse

As a part of a bigger project, I'm trying to figure out how to move an object (ellipse in this case). Here is the part of my code that is giving me trouble:

```
//updating the position of the ellipse
let updatePoints (form : Form) (coords : vector3Dlist ) dtheta showtime =
  let mutable fsttuple = 0
  let mutable sndtuple = 0
  for i in 0..coords.Length-1 do
    fsttuple <- (int (round (fst coords.[i])))
    sndtuple <- (int (round (snd coords.[i])))
    (fillEllipseform.Paint.Add(fun draw->
    let brush=new SolidBrush(Color.Red)  
    draw.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush,fsttuple,sndtuple,10.0f,10.0f)))
    form.Refresh ()
```

The function uses a list of coordinates to get the new x and y values. This gives me the syntax error "possible overload". I think I'm looking to do something like this:

```
fillEllipseform.X <- fsttuple
```

How exactly do i change the x/y-coordinates? The .NET library is very limited with F# example when it comes to the ellipse.

Comment: `Form` does not have `X` and `Y` properties.  It has a `Location` property of type `Point`.  Try fillEllipseform.Location <- Point(fsttuple, sndtuple)`

Comment: For being more idiomatic, you might want to remove the mutable variables here, there's really no need for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here is that `FillEllipse` takes a `Brush`, and then either 4 `int`s, or 4 `float32`s. At the moment you are passing in a mixture, so it isn't sure which overload to pick.

If you chose `float32` and without rounding (not sure what the type of `vector3Dlist` is) then a working version would look like:

```
//updating the position of the ellipse
let updatePoints (form : Form) (coords : vector3Dlist ) dtheta showtime =
  let mutable fsttuple = 0.0f
  let mutable sndtuple = 0.0f
  for i in 0..coords.Length-1 do
    fsttuple <- fst coords.[i]
    sndtuple <- snd coords.[i]
    (fillEllipseform.Paint.Add(fun draw->
    let brush=new SolidBrush(Color.Red)  
    draw.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush,fsttuple,sndtuple,10.0f,10.0f)))
    form.Refresh ()
```